# Fiware-Orion: Geolocation

Tags: fiware-orion

Hi I'm a student and I'm working for the first time on the broker. I understood how the creation of entities works and their updating through "update" queries. My question is: you can create an entity that contains variables (eg geolocation) defined with value "null" or "zero" and then initialize them with values that interest me. So as to have dynamic and non-static variables (ie that require user update)?
Or do we need interaction with the CEP to do this?

From what I have read in the fiware-orion guide when I create an entity (ex car having attributes and velocity coordinates: geopoint). The values of these 2 attributes must be set in a static way (ex: speed 100 and position coordinates 40.257, 2.187). If I understand the values of these attributes I can only update them by making an update query. So my question is:
Is it possible to update the value of the attributes that contain the position or the speed of the car in a dynamic way, ie without having to write the values from the keyboard? Or does this require the use of the CEP of orion?
If I could not explain myself more generally I would like to know if it is possible to follow the progress of a moving car without me having to add the values from the keyboard.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure of getting the full picture of what you are proposing... Do you mean "attribute" by "variable"? Could you edit your question post to include an example, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orion Context Brokker exposes a [REST-based API](https://www.restapitutorial.com) that (among other things) allows you to create, update and query entities. From the point of view of Orion, it doesn't matter who is the one invoking the API: it can be done manually (for instance, using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/)) or can be an automated system developed by you or a third party (for instance, a software running in a sensor in the car that measures the speed and periodically sends an update using a wireless communication network).

From a client-server point of view (in the case you are familiar with these concepts), Orion takes the *server of the API* role and the one updating the speed (either manually or automatically) takes the role of *client of the API*.